# How is this try-except clause working to identify an integer?

Tags: python

I am new to programming, and I am trying to understand how Python interprets commands, and in this case I am having trouble understanding how Python knows to identify an integer, floating number, or string using a try-except clause. Here is my code (please excuse the cheekiness)

```
print("DETECTING INPUT TYPE WITH LIMITED CHANCES")
print("Enter an integer and ONLY AN INTEGER. YOU HAVE ONLY 5 CHANCES")
n=0
final=0
for n in range(5):
    abc=input()
    try:
        int(abc) #This line checks for whether the input is an integer. If this is a floating number, the int() operator executes and
        # converts the number to an integer
        final=1
        break
    except:
        try:
            float(abc)
            print("WHAT DID I TELL YOU? YOU PUT IN A FLOATING NUMBER! DO IT RIGHT!")
            print("Enter an integer and ONLY AN INTEGER")
        except:
            print("...you put a string didn't you? HOW DARE YOU DEFY THIS PROGRAM? DO IT RIGHT!")
            print("Enter an integer and ONLY AN INTEGER")
if final==1:
    print("Good... very good, here is your number:",abc)
else:
    print("You were given 5 chances and you couldn't get it right.")
```

This code works as intended, but how does the program throw an exception to allow the try-except clause to execute when I put a floating number? For example, here is what happens when I put "1.0" for my input when executing the program:

```
DETECTING INPUT TYPE WITH LIMITED CHANCES
Enter an integer and ONLY AN INTEGER. YOU HAVE ONLY 5 CHANCES

1.0
WHAT DID I TELL YOU? YOU PUT IN A FLOATING NUMBER! DO IT RIGHT!
Enter an integer and ONLY AN INTEGER
```

And then what it looks like when I correct myself and input an integer:

```
1
Good... very good, here is your number: 1
```

However, if I manually type in the following into the console, I do not get an error. Instead, the int() command does what it is supposed to, and converts my floating number to an integer.

```
abc=1.0

int(abc)
Out[3]: 1
```

What does the try-except clause do to the int() operator to raise an exception and allow my code to execute properly?

Thank you!

Comment: I think the problem is that the input() function always returns a string, so the error is from `int("1.0")`. This is why it is usually bad practice to use try/except without specifying which kind of error you're expecting.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll keep that in mind for the future when using try/except clauses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `input` is a string. To replicate it in the console you should do

```
abc = "1.0"
```

and then `int(abc)` will raise a ValueError as expected.